# analytic solution to second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Is there any way to solve this equation
analytically ?

$m\ddot{x} = B_0 \left( \frac{1}{x^4} - \frac{1}{(L-x)^4}  \right)$

[its supposed to describe this system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbY3I.png)

Comment: Could you tell the physics behind your question  ? A particle influenced by conflicting potentials ?

Comment: @JeanMarie i mounted an experiment on my mechanics laboratory, a slider on an air track with two magnets atached to it oscilating between other two identical magnets, the opposite poles are face to face, this is the equation i proposed to describe the movement of the slider, i think its a magnetic oscillator

Comment: I am afraid that your only hope is to reduce the order (what @Cesareo did) and continue with numerical integration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

$$
m \ddot x\dot x= B_0 \left( \frac{\dot x}{x^4} - \frac{\dot x}{(L-x)^4}  \right)
$$